# org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory maven dependancy

Tags: java, maven, jboss

I am using following code in my program, which is jndi lookup for jboss 7 client.

```
public static Context getInitialContext() throws NamingException {
      Properties properties = new Properties();
      properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
              "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
      properties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");
      properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "remote://localhost:4447");
      return new InitialContext(properties);
}
```

when I run my program from eclipse->Run as java application it works fine provided I give jboss/bin/client/jboss-client.jar in my classpath.

I need to include the same jar in my maven dependency.

What is the maven dependancy pom for "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory" or where can I find the dependency pom.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

Use this dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
  <artifactId>jboss-remote-naming</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.7.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the link below which has the dependency

mvnrepository.com/artifact/jboss/jboss-client

If that is not the jar you are looking for, add the jar file to Maven repository by executing the below command in command prompt.

```
call mvn install:install-file -Dfile=jboss\jboss-client\1.0\jboss-client.jar -DgroupId=jboss-client -DartifactId=jboss-client -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

-Dfile - Should be the path where you jar file is.
-DgroupId - Group ID (Root folder)
-DartifactId - Jar file name (A sub folder will be created inside root folder)
-Dversion=1.0 - Version of the jar ( Another sub folder will be created inside file name folder)

Doing this will add a new repository to your maven repository (.m2) if you have not changed the maven repository location.